# Applying overflow to box shadow only

Tags: css, html-input

I'm trying to build a input ranged slider bar. But I'm facing a problem.

```css
body {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #151515;
}
#rangeValue {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 6em;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.range {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab) !important;
    width: 400px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #111;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -507px 0 0 500px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="rangeValue">0</span>
    <Input class="range" type="range" name "" value="0" min="0" max="1000"></Input>
</div>
```

The problem is: I want this big red area stay inside the input slider, even while drawing. The only **solution** is apply `overflow: hidden` to `.range`, but I'll **lose** the blue dot button.
Is there a way to fix this applying `overflow: hidden` just to `box-shadow?` Or any other clue to make it works properly?

The final result shoud be something like this =>

[image: final result]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help. but here is a refactoring I did. maybe you can do some changes to fit your task.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <span id="rangeValue">0</span>
    <Input type="range" name="" id="range" value="0" min="0" max="100"></Input>
</div>
</body>
  
  <script src=""></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #151515;
}
#rangeValue {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 6em;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* Input Thumb */
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff4500;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #555;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff4500;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #555;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff4500;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #555;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}


/* Input Track */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track  {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

JS

```
const rangeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]')

function handleInputChange(e) {
  let target = e.target
  if (e.target.type !== 'range') {
    target = document.getElementById('range')
  }
  
  const min = target.min
  const max = target.max
  const val = target.value
  
  target.style.backgroundSize = (val - min) * 100 / (max - min) + '% 100%'
}

rangeInputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange)
})
```

You can tweak it to your liking.
I hope this helps

Comment: Do you know how can I apply the background: linear-gradient to untracked area?